# Scanning all the links (URLs) in a website and using each of them in selenium get() method

Tags: url, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to get all the URLs in a website so that I can use it to open the webpage using Selenium get() method. After opening a page I intend to fetch few data from the webpage and move on to next link.

Can you help me out with the best method for doing this and provide a sample code for the same.

Comment: please try it yourself and show us ur effort,if it still doesnt work,we'l be happy to help..

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways of doing this but this is the first way I thought of.

```
    // Create your driver of choice
    WebDriver fDriver;
    fDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // Direct the driver to the site that you want to get all the links from
    fDriver.get("Site URL here...");

    // Grab all the anchor tags on the page you're currently on.
    List<WebElement> anchors = fDriver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    // Create a 2nd List to hold the URLs of the anchor tags.
    List<String> allURLs = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate through all the anchors that you got.
    for (WebElement a : anchors) {

        // Print out the URL of the anchor.
        System.out.println(a.getAttribute("href"));

        // Store the URL of the List.
        allURLs.add(a.getAttribute("href"));
    }

    // Now just get the URL you want to use from the list...
    String siteURL = allURLs.get(0);
    // and enter it into the get() method of the driver.
    fDriver.get(siteURL);
```

The 2nd part of using ALL the URLs with the get method is up to you to figure out but I think I've given you a good start. Hope it helps!